# Octave - permanent load package system-wide (for all users)

Tags: user-interface, octave, global, package

I've read both the FAQ answer on the Wiki for Octave and this Stack Overflow post:  [How to load packages in Octave permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987704/how-to-load-packages-in-octave-permanently) but apparently I'm still not grasping the meaning of the answers that were given.  Questions abound...

- if I want to make a package universally available upon program start-up for any user on my computer, is the Wiki saying I should edit the file "octaverc", which is read-only and immune to permission changes with chmod?
- in order to change this file, do I need to download the dev package or am I supposed to go deeper and try to edit where Octave looks for its start-up commands to launch using a custom version of octaverc?
- if I could edit the octaverc file, do I just add the line below the automatic load line?

I know this is nice and simple if I'm running Octave from the command line and want to load a package for one session's use only by typing "pkg load signal" at the Octave command prompt, but the end goal is to have it always available because I can't seem to load packages from within the new Octave GUI.  If there's a way to do this instead, it would also do the trick.

An etiquette conundrum - I would have just commented on the previous Stack Overflow post linked above, but haven't got the necessary reputation around here...what's best practice?

Comment: It seems you're trying to edit the file `/etc/octaverc`, while there should be a local hidden file `~/.octaverc` in your home directory. If it doesn't exist, just create it.

Comment: that file would only affect the current user, and it appears he wants to know how to make that change for all users.

Comment: Then edit /etc/octave.conf as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `~/.octaverc` is user specific. If you want to make system-wide changes, change the system Octave configuration file. If you built Octave from source with default options, it can be one of the following files:

- `/usr/local/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc` configuration file for all Octave in the system (with prefix `/usr/local`)
- `/usr/local/share/octave/4.0.3/m/startup/octaverc` configuration file for Octave version 4.0.3
- `/usr/local/share/octave/4.2.1/m/startup/octaverc` configuration file for Octave version 4.2.1

If you have installed from your package manager, the file will probably be somewhere in `/etc/octave.conf` which is then linked from `/usr/share/octave/...`

Comment: Thanks to all - from the package manager, it was indeed in /etc/octave.conf so a sudo gvim edit was all that was in order.